# How to return a object directly from async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

- I have Redux store function where I have to make an AJAX and update the state accordingly. However, I created the following function which dost not update the x value before return the state. So, I create `async` function.

```
  var x =[]
  lookup(
      "GET",
      "api/post/",
      (response, status: number) => {
        Object.assign(x, response);
      }
    );
  console.log(x,'her x stay just ampty array []');
switch (action.type) {
    case "SetData":
      return { ...state, data: x };
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

---

- In the following example I am trying to get the response outside the function `lookup` so I created a sync called `newData` how to make it rerun the `res` directly without asining a `var` inside it.

```
const newData = async () => {
    var x: any = [];
    await lookup(
      "GET",
      "api/post/",
      (response: myArrays["posts"], status: number) => {
        Object.assign(x, response);
      }
    );
    return x;
  };
  console.log(newData().then((res) => res));


switch (action.type) {
    
    case "SetData":
      return { ...state, data: newData().then((res) => {return res}) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

---

- please note: I can't use React.usesState() inside my store function because it is not a component function.

Comment: It sounds like you need to familiarize your self some more with async programming in javascript (or in general). https://www.google.com/search?q=understanding+promises gives you allot of results to begin trom. What prompts this response from me is your use in the console.log function. Calling then on a Promise (what an async function returns) does not magically turn it into a synchronous "value", you can use the "Then" function of a promise to transform it's data or perform an action when the data is ready, but the Then function returns just a new promise. We have all been where you are now.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do this the way you're trying to do this. What you need to do is something like this:

```
const data = await newData();
dispatch({ type: "SetData", data })
```

Answer (score 1):

**A Redux reducer cannot be asynchronous.**  A reducer takes a previous state and an action and maps it to a new action.  That's it.  You cannot dispatch an action or trigger an API call from a reducer.

The API call needs to be done elsewhere -- in your component, in a [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) action creator, etc.  Once the API call has been completed, then you dispatch a "SetData" action with the data that you recieved.  The reducer then updates the `state` based on this data.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```js
const newData = async () => {
    return await lookup(
      "GET",
      "api/post/",
      (response: myArrays["posts"], status: number) => {
        Object.assign(x, response);
      }
    );
};

console.log(await newData());
```

This way you can avoid assigning another `var` inside `newData` as you asked.

Also check out this [redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic) on how to do async data fetching with redux.

Comment: `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts(1308)`

Comment: Try adding `async` to the wrapping function as the message says.

Comment: you can't do like `async console.log(await newData());`